# Parse char* mac-string to uint8_t array

Tags: string, convert, c-string, bytes

I have to handle a String coming in over UART containing a bunch of information, part of it is a MAC-address that I get by using String.substring(a, b) returning a 12-char String representing a mac-address `"B8C9A45BA770"` <- (just an example).

**I need the format of the mac-address to be a uint8_t array like so
`{ 0xB8, 0xC9, 0xA4, 0x5B, 0xA7, 0x70 }`.**

So I need a function to convert a String to a uint8_t*. Sadly I have no clue how to convert this. There has so be an easy way right? its "C8" to 0xC8 and so forth...

Any ideas on this?

Comment: You can use sscanf

Comment: It would be easier to see you confusion if you actually showed some code.

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". You are supposed to do a good part of research on your own. So please [edit] your question and add what your research revealed, and why it did not help you. Hint: a quick web search on "c++ convert string to integer" give a lot of good hits...

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd go with a basic implementation such as this one.

```
const uint8_t MAC_length = 6;
uint8_t* MAC_buffer[6];

uint8_t fromHexChar(char c)
{
    uint8_t result = 0
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
        result = c - '0';
    else if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F'))
        result = 10 + c - 'A';
    else if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f'))
        result = 10 + c - 'a';
    return result
}

uint8_t* toMAC(String s)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < MAC_length; i++)
    {
        MAC_buffer[i] = (fromHexChar(s.charAt(2*i)) << 4) | fromHexChar(s.charAt(2*i + 1));
    }
    return MAC_buffer;
}
```

Probably it can be optimized, but this is such a simple job and to be used so rarely that I think this is enough.

Important: I did not test this code, so there may be bugs inside.

If you need to start from an arbitrary point in the String instead of at the beginning, you simply have to modify it this way:

```
uint8_t* toMAC(String s, uint8_t startIdx)
...
        MAC_buffer[i] = fromHexChar(s.charAt(2*i + startIdx)) << 4 | fromHexChar(s.charAt(2*i + startIdx + 1));
```

Note for future me: I checked both on a simulator and in the code, and `charAt` is safe to use even when the index is outside the string boundaries (it simply returns 0).

Comment: Many thanks! Hopefully I can try it out within my code today, if not it's going to be next week :)

Comment: I have a question though: Why are you using globals in this case? Wouldn't it be better to have a pure function by removing the buffer from global scope and adding into the toMAC-function? That's what I changed anyways

Comment: @HaraldLesan: If you make `MAC_buffer` local to `toMAC()`, you have to make it `static`, otherwise you would be getting back a pointer to unallocated stack space, which you cannot dereference (it's undefined behavior). But then, `toMAC()` is not pure. If you really want it pure, make it return the array encapsulated inside a `struct`.

Comment: Thank you @EdgarBonet, as always your contributions are always a great addition :) never thought about encapsulating in structs, I'll have to dig a bit deeper

Comment: @HaraldLesan As Edgar said, putting it inside the function will remove it from memory when the function exits, so you won't be able to use it outside. If you really want to avoid that global, the solution I would use is to allocate it outside and pass it to the function: `uint8_t* toMAC(String s, uint8_t *MAC_buffer, uint8_t MAC_length)`. But generally speaking I avoid dynamic memory on uC, so usually buffers are usually global in my code.

Comment: I might be nitpicking here, but `charToHex` should probably be called `fromHexChar` or similar. We're not converting anything __to__ hex, we're converting __from__ hex.

Comment: @tkausl honestly I had a similar thought when writing, then did not found any valid name (it is a char to an integer, but how to express that it needed to be in hex?). I did not think of naming it "from" something. I'm changing it :) thank you

Comment: @frarugi87: You can still allocate the buffer outside and pass it to the called function, without using heap. It merely has to have a lifetime longer than the called function. If the buffer is local to the calling function, a) it will still be invisible to other functions; b) will not use heap; and c) will be de-allocated when the calling function returns.

Comment: @JRobert Yes, the modification to allocate it outside and simply pass it to the function was what I wrote it in a comment above. Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: That was specifically to address "avoid dynamic memory".; that automatic memory is a another non-global option.